# Will using CSS rules like transform or flexbox be visible correctly when generating PDF from HTML + CSS?

Tags: html, css, node.js, pdf-generation

quick question I was just wondering can I use any CSS property/rules, when generating a PDF from a HTML + CSS template, like transforms, background gradients or grid displays? (I dont enjoy using `<table>` all the time)

dunno if it matters but im using html-pdf npm package

Comment: I just tried out grid and that doesn't work so I'm back to using table for my layouts, is there any resource out there that tells you what can be used and what can't? like with emails there is this site https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Comment: Grid structures are fine for HTML monolithic "single page" output but breakdown when Pagination and keep rules are applied. Grid blocks typically map to floats and floats do not split content at pages